# Open neighbourhood of dense set is a cover

Tags: general-topology

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set and let $\{ x_m\}_{m \ge 0} \subset X$ be dense in $X$.  Now let $\{Q(x_m)\}_{m \ge 0}$ be a sequence of open sets such that $Q(x_m)$ is an open ball around $x_m$. Does it necessarily follow that $\{Q(x_m)\}_{m \ge 0}$ is a cover of $X$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $n = 1$, $X = [0,1]$ and $D = \{x_m\} = \mathbb Q \cap (0,1)$. For each $x \in D$ let $Q(x) = (x-r_x,x+r_x)$ with $r_x = \min (x,1-x)$. Then no $Q(x)$ contains the points $0,1$.

Comment: is there a descripiton for how strange the set of points which are not covered is?

Comment: @GiuseppeTenaglia I do not know such a description.

Comment: In general, a space $X$ may have a dense open subset $D\ne X,$ so $\{D\}$ is an open cover of $D$ but not a cover of $X.$ E.g. $D=\{1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ and $X=D\cup\{0\}.$